# How to assert a given state leads to a another state with variables in TLA+?

Tags: tla+

Sorry the title is a bit cryptic. I have a TLA+ spec that defines two sets:

```
variables Requests = {}, Outcomes = {};
```

I have one set of workers adding requests, and another set or workers fulfilling them and writing to `Outcomes`. Each request has a unique `Id`, which the matching `Outcome` entry will then also contain.

I want to guarantee that any request added to the `Requests` set is eventually matched by a structure with the same `Id` in the `Outcomes` set. I've been trying to do this using the "leads to", `~>`, operator, but can't figure out how to resolve the `Id` matching portion.

I've naively tried something like:

```
RequestsAreFulfilled == \E req \in Requests: TRUE 
                        ~> \E outcome \in Outcomes : outcome.id = req.id
```

But this obviously breaks since `req` is not defined in the second expression. I've considered something along the lines of the second express being "Then there is a state where all Request items are matched by Outcome items", but that doesn't work since the system never terminates - there may very well always be more requests in the `Requests` set, since `Outcomes` is always playing catch-up.

What is a way for me to assert that a request is eventually matched with an outcome with the same id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLC has some trouble proving liveness properties with nonconstant sets. Let's start with the fixed case, where you have a finite, fixed set of ids. Then we can specify the relation as

```
\A id \in Ids: (\E r \in req: r.id = id) ~> (\E o \in out: o.id = id)
```

In this case, though, we're better off using structures, as they're easier to understand and express shared relationships better.

```
requested = [i \in Ids |-> FALSE];
processed = [i \in Ids |-> FALSE];

\A id \in Ids: requested[i] ~> processed[i]
```

or

```
messages = [i \in Ids |-> [requested |-> FALSE, processed |-> FALSE]]
\A id \in Ids: 
   LET m == messages[i]
   IN  m.requested ~> m.processed
```

If you want an infinite number of messages, one way to get TLC to handle liveness checks is to use a fixed set of ids then add logic to "recycle" finished messages - set both `requested` and `processed` to FALSE. Then we can use the always-eventually operator, `[]<>`, to express this:

```
\A id \in Ids: []<>(requested[i] => processed[i])
```

Comment: So; I think I marked this too quickly; TLC is angry with me, erroring out saying "TLC cannot handle the temporal formula line 42", which is the `\A id \in Ids: requested[i] ~> processed[i]` formula.

The exact TLA+ spec I'm using is this: https://gist.github.com/jakewins/b431d83d8833953ea73a5d02d6724189

Am I using the formula incorrectly?

Comment: @jakewins Ids has to be a constant or an operator, in your spec you have it as a variable.